# How to insert a page break in openpyxl

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I see in the documentation for openpyxl that it supports page breaks.  I have searched the docs and googled, but I cannot figure out how to insert a page break manually. I want a new page when I change the year in my report. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

### For version 2.6.2

@goocheeze answer is correct except...

```
ws.page_breaks.append(page_break)  # insert page break
```

should be

```
ws.row_breaks.append(page_break)  # insert page break
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use worksheet.page_breaks.append(page_break) to insert a page_break, see [openpyxl source](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/pagebreak.html#PageBreak.append) for detial. Here is an example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.pagebreak import Break

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
row_number = 20  # the row that you want to insert page break
page_break = Break(id=row_number)  # create Break obj
ws.page_breaks.append(page_break)  # insert page break
```

I don't know why the author use the name "id" to refer to the page break row number, use "row_number" may be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
row_break = RowBreak()
row_break.append(Break(id=row_num))
worksheet.row_breaks = row_break
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I moved my program, python and IDE to a new computer. I was using "ws.page_breaks.append(page_break)" and got an error about not being able to append a tuple, even though it works fine on my other computer.

I changed the code using a "try/ except" format to allow for both "page_breaks/ row_breaks".

My solution is as follows:

```
    try:
        ws_list[i].page_breaks.append(Break(id=oi))
    except:
        ws_list[i].row_breaks.append(Break(id=oi))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Александр Дмитриев

Here is a full working example that scans down column A looking for when the year changes and inserts a page break between such rows.

```py
import openpyxl, os
from openpyxl.worksheet.pagebreak import Break, RowBreak
path = 'path to folder with file'
f = 'pb.xlsx'  # data file input is as follows
'''
A       B
------  ------
2020    a
2020    b
2021    c
2021    d
2022    e
2023    f
'''
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=os.path.join(path, f))
worksheet=wb.active
row_break = RowBreak()
for i in range(worksheet.max_row):
    r = i + 1
    A = worksheet['A%s'%r]._value
    if i and A != oldA:
        row_break.append(Break(id=i))  # i to insert before this row, r
    oldA = A

worksheet.row_breaks = row_break
wb.save(os.path.join(path,'so.xlsx'))
wb.close()
```

The resulting spreadsheet has page breaks between the rows in which the year changes: there are 4 pages for the sample input file.